# Can't add a role to a user. JDA

Tags: java, discord-jda

I want to make a command, where when a user types a msg, the user gets a role. In this case, I am using this line of code.

```
Role zhopa = event.getGuild().getRoleById("581237466552336394");
event.getGuild().addRoleToMember(event.getMember().getUser().getId(), zhopa).queue();
```

I have also tried

```
Role zhopa = event.getGuild().getRoleById("581237466552336394");
event.getGuild().addRoleToMember(event.getGuild().getMember(event.getAuthor()), zhopa).queue();
```

I have tried many stuff/codes and still not working :/ Can somebody please help me?

language: java, JDA.
https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#addRoleToMember(long,net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Role)

Comment: I see no problem with the code snippets you provided, try using a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:** my issue was that the bot role was under "zhopa" role

Answer (score 0):

I guess its old, but just initiate a selfmember variable it solved my problem.
`

```
        Member user = event.getMember();
        Member Bot = guild.getSelfMember();
        Role role = guild.getRolesByName("Member", true).get(0);
        guild.addRoleToMember(user, role).queue();
```

`